# Forecasting proportions of aggregations vs direct forecasting

Tags: time-series, forecasting, aggregation, compositional-data

Assume one has to predict the sales of a shop on a daily basis. The sales per day $S(t)$ clearly follow a strong weekly pattern, but also a yearly pattern, a general trend and of course some noise are present.

I wonder to which extend the following approach could make sense:

Predict the weekly sales $\tilde{S}(w) := \sum_{t \in week(w)} S(t)$ first and in a second step the proportion of each weekday Mo-Su of the total weekly sales, i.e. $(Mo(w),\ldots, Su(w)) \in [0,1]^7$, where it is known than $Su(w) = 0$. Then, for a given day $t$ in week $w$, which is a Monday say, we have $S(t) \approx \tilde{S}(w) \cdot Mo(w)$.

My question is under which conditions this approach could make sense, i.e. instead of directly predicting the quantity of interest, predict some aggregation first and then the appropriate proportion of the aggregation. In the shop-sales example above, I have the impression that both weekly sales and weekday patterns (e.g. the monday proportion) are more "stable" than the daily sales pattern.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is under which conditions this approach could make sense [...]

Kourentzes has done a lot of work on temporal aggregation.

See [here](http://kourentzes.com/forecasting/2014/05/26/improving-forecasting-via-multiple-temporal-aggregation/), [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Nikolaos_Kourentzes/publication/314089402_Demand_forecasting_by_temporal_aggregation_using_optimal_or_multiple_aggregation_levels/links/58b47bdd92851cf7ae941127/Demand-forecasting-by-temporal-aggregation-using-optimal-or-multiple-aggregation-levels.pdf) and [here](http://kourentzes.com/forecasting/2014/04/19/improving-forecasting-by-estimating-time-series-structural-components-across-multiple-frequencies/).

He has also made the R code for a lot of his methods available.

> predict some aggregation first and then the appropriate proportion of the aggregation.

Note that aggregating across time is not the only option. In sales demand forecasting, it is also common to aggregate across product and geographical combinations. See [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/344813/89649) for more details.