# Forecasting sales for thousands of stores individually with multiple features associated

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, multilevel-analysis, lstm

I have data of 2000 stores with associated 145 features (example: ambience, holidays, no. of brands) and their monthly sales for 2 years. It means that for every store I have sales data and other features for 24 months.

I have to forecast sales for every store on a monthly basis. I have basic idea of LSTM but here its like 2000 time series with 145 features with just 24 data points or in other words for one time step, I have 2000 series with 145 features. what is the best approach to model so that I don't have to build model separately for each store.

Comment: [Product Demand Forecasting for Thousands of Products Across Multiple Stores](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/344705/product-demand-forecasting-for-thousands-of-products-across-multiple-stores/344813#344813)

Comment: [Is it possible to automate time series forecasting?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/380599/is-it-possible-to-automate-time-series-forecasting/380689#380689)

Comment: I really wonder how you solved this problem because I am doing a similar study now.

Comment: Also search this site for "hierarchical forecasting", and have a look through this [stored search](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=hierarchical+forecasting++++site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Frobjhyndman.com%2Fhyndsight%2F)